# tree in java to add any no of nodes

Tags: java, tree

i want to build a tree in java. operations such as insert delete update. how to go about it? I dont want a binary tree, i want to add  children based on user input

i have implemented the following

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Tree {

private Node root;

public Tree(String rootData)
{
    root=new Node();
    root.data=rootData;
    root.children=new ArrayList<Node>();
}

public void addChild(String name)
{

}
}

import java.util.*;

class Node { 
      String data;
      Node parent;
     List<Node> children;

 public Node()
 {
     data=null;
     children=null;
     parent=null;
 }
 public Node(String name)
 {
   Node n=new Node(name);
   n.data=name;
   n.children=new ArrayList<Node>();
 }
```

}

Comment: Looks like you want to use xml.

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: creating node on user input . e.g supose the user wants to create home directory and music ,documents and movies as sub directories

Comment: You need to be more specific when you say user input. Are they interacting with the command line and typing text in? If so, how? Show some example input and explain what the result would be. Also, you need to specify what the real problem is - obtaining user input? parsing the input? actually adding it to the tree? Feel free to edit your question to add this information.

Comment: after i get the user  input how to create nodes. like e.g if user types home.. so how to create a home node. and ya user will be typing in the console

Comment: Suppose i ask the user to enter the root element, and then the user types home.. so how can i create a node home by passing home as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;


public class MyTree extends JFrame{

private JTree tree;
private DefaultTreeModel model;
private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode;


public MyTree()
{
     DefaultMutableTreeNode philosophersNode = getTree();
        model = new DefaultTreeModel(philosophersNode);
        tree = new JTree(model);
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add ");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            addNode();
          }
        });
        JButton removeButton = new JButton("Delete");
        removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
              removeSelectedNode();
          }
        });
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        inputPanel.add(addButton);
        inputPanel.add(removeButton);

        Container container = getContentPane();

        container.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        container.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 500);
        setVisible(true);

}

 private DefaultMutableTreeNode getSelectedNode() {

        return (DefaultMutableTreeNode)   tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
      }

 private DefaultMutableTreeNode getTree() {
         rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        return rootNode;
      }

 private void removeSelectedNode() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = getSelectedNode();
        if (selectedNode != null){
             if(selectedNode.toString()=="Root")
                {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MyTree.this, "Cannot delete root element", "Error",
                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }else{

          model.removeNodeFromParent(selectedNode);
                }
        }

      }

 private void addNode() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = getSelectedNode();
        if (parent == null) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MyTree.this, "Select an area.",   "Error",
              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

          return;
        }
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(MyTree.this, "Enter Name:");
        model.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name), parent,     parent.getChildCount());

      }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MyTree();
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you want. You might want to look into the DefaultTreeModel implementation or the TreeModel interface for the JTree, perhaps. No need to reinvent the wheel. More often than not the wheel will look distinctly triangular.

*Anyway*, this might help a bit:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Tree {
    private Node root;

    public Tree(String rootData)
    {
        root=new Node();
        root.data=rootData;
        root.children=new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public List<Node> getPathToNode(Node node) {
        Node currentNode = node;
        List<Node> reversePath = new ArrayList<Node>();
        reversePath.add(node);
        while (!(this.root.equals(currentNode)) {
            currentNode = currentNode.getParentNode();
            reversePath.add(currentNode);
        }
        Collections.reverse(reversePath); // now the list is root -> node
        return reversePath;              
    }

}

import java.util.*;

class Node { 
    String data;
    Node parent;
    List<Node> children;

    /* I would remove this constructor or at least initialize the field to non-null defaults. This is bloody dangerous. */
    public Node()
    {
        data=null;
        children=null;
        parent=null;
    }

    public Node(String name)
    {
        Node n=new Node(name);
        n.data=name;
        n.children=new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public void addChild(String name) {
        this.addChild(new Node(name));
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(Node child) {
        this.children.remove(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(String name) {
        this.removeChild(this.getChild(name));
    }

    public Node getChild(int childIndex) {
        return this.children.get(childIndex);
    }

    public Node getChild(String childName) {
        for (Node child : this.children) {
            if (child.getName().equals(childName)) { return child; }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Node getParentNode() {
        return this.parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nice explanation about generic tree at the following link http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/05/java-data-structure-generic-tree.html   hope it helps